# Which attributes should be stored in Session

Tags: php, sql, session, session-variables

I know that Session is used to keep track of the client's actions, or simply like a Log in, if there's a Session, show stuff, if not then he's a Guest, and we store as well values or attributes in this Session.

Until now, I always store the User's ID inside the Session, as a primary attribute that would help me recognize him in other pages.

`$_SESSION['userID'] = $userID; //example: 100, 101, 102...`

I can retrieve this ID and fetch data from the Database according to this ID.

```
$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = ".$userID;
```

Is this the proper way to use Session? The ID should not be stored in Session? Any security Risks? If it shouldn't be stored, then how do I recognize a User?

Comment: Storing just the `userID` in the session is fine. The problems come when you start storing passwords and other sensitive information in a session. The `userID` itself isn't sensitive information.

Comment: perhaps you could use unique `access token` kinda of thing which will be valid only for registered and logged in users. If you found valid access token, get the ID and to the stuff. That way, even if access token is hijacked, person might not be able to guess the way it is generated

Comment: Only by userId you can't authorize anyone. Its just guessing any id, if you hit one, you are logged in...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, storing userID in a session is just fine, just don't use it to authenticate users, use a authentication ID instead.

Other than that there should be no security risks.

Just don't use them for storing sensitive information (passwords and similar).

Comment: So I should have 2 IDs for each user? An Incremented ID used for authentication, like `100, 101, 102` and a Generated ID used for display `user.php?id=Sjd8923nqwe` ?

Comment: No need to do that, if that ID isn't something confidential (most likely it isn't) then you can show them the id, no point in hiding it. Just don't use them for client identification when they are in plain text stored in clients cookies, cause that would allow the user to just change the ID and become another client without their creditentials.

Answer (score 0):

The session is never transfered to the user. The browser get's a cookie called PHPSESSID containing the ID of your session.

This means: No matter what you store in the session, it's completely kept on the server.

From this point of view, there are no security problems to the data in the session. You can store there whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Store as little information as possible in the session scope.

The reason is that with modern browsers, the same session is shared between tabs in the same browser instance, or in separate browser instances.  In other words, if you open your application in firefox for example, then launch firefox again, the new firefox window will inherit the session from the old one.

Now the bad part.  If you have a session.abc = 123 in your browser 1, and then do something in browser 2 to change it to 456, and then go back to browser 1 and make a page request of some sort (like submitting a form), it will use the new value of session.abc on that request.

We've been burned by this.  People have inadvertently updated the wrong record.